# Combined querys in one query

Tags: pointers, parse-platform

### **CODE**

```
PFQuery *quizQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Quiz"];        
PFQuery *resultsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Results"];        
[quizQuery whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"quizPlayed.ObjectId" inQuery:resultsQuery];

//where quizPlayed is a pointer pointing to the quiz table.
```

this code doesn't work.

what i want is, I want all quiz objects from "Quiz" table which are in the results table.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: How about `@"quizPlayed.objectId"`?

Comment: nope that didn't work. already tried that.

Comment: `@"quizPlayed.id"`? Are you getting any error messages in your console? Drop by [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61287/parse-com).

Comment: Error: invalid field name: quizPlayed.id (Code: 105, Version: 1.2.18)

Comment: Can we talk about it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61287/parse-com)? I'd rather not clutter the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javier de la Cueva ·  · Facebook Platform Team
Hi Vamsi,

In the code provided, you are comparing a pointer with the objectId, we do not support that.

You can achieve this by having pointers from ObjectRelations to Object and querying ObjectRelations that have the required objectID and getting all the Objects it points to.

Please go to parse.com/help and ask to our community in order to help more clarification for your implementation.

Thanks.